# gdk_screen_get_default() and get_width()/height() segfault

Tags: c, gtk

I just cracked open Foundations of GTK Development and was trying to do something creative that would be useful in the future of the application I'm developing at work.

Specifically,

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    GtkWidget *window = NULL, *label = NULL;
    GdkScreen *screen = NULL;
    gint width = 0, height = 0;
    char *resolution = NULL;

    gtk_init(&argc, &argv);

    if((screen = gdk_screen_get_default()) != NULL)
    {
        width  = gdk_screen_get_width(screen);
        height = gdk_screen_get_height(screen);
    }

    sprintf(resolution, "%d x %d", width, height);

    ...
```

causes a segfault when executed. I am certain that I'm making a noob mistake and that eventually I'll recognize the error for what it is, but at present I am unable to figure it out. The Google results I've been able to generate haven't been too useful either.

Any help?

Comment: This question is a good example of why you should always try to make a minimal example that reproduces your problem; you would have stripped out all the GTK code and narrowed the problem down to `sprintf`. Then you probably would have read the manpage on `sprintf` and figured it out yourself ;-)

Comment: Without question. I was originally only going to post the GTK bits, but that would've been the inverse of what you described and only caused more confusion. =D

Comment: Well, when you tested the GTK code before you posted it, then you would have realized that that wasn't what was causing the segfault ;-)

Comment: Precisely. I meant my initial inclination was going to produce the opposite results of the sound advice in your first comment, haha.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One problem is that the variable `resolution` points to NULL, so the sprintf to that will definitely result in undefined behavior (likely a crash).  The code should either allocate memory for that variable (e.g., `resolution = malloc(somesize);`) or declare it on the stack (e.g., `char resolution[somesize];`)

Comment: Ha. Yeah, that was it. Thank you very much.

Noob mistake indeed. ;)